# IOS FoodTracker Tutorial: Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'path'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm finishing IOS Swift Tutorial "[FoodTracker](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1)", but there's a error that I can find solution and I dont understand what is wrong and how to fixit:

The error:

> Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'path'

This error is shown for variable "Meal.ArchiveUrl.path" at below code.

My code, at MealtableViewController (that its equal to IOS tutorial):

```
private func saveMeals(){
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(meals, toFile: Meal.ArchiveUrl.path )

    if isSuccessfulSave {
        os_log("Meals successfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

    } else {
        os_log("Failed to save meals...", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)

    }
}
```

And at Meal.swift, there's the declaration:

```
/MARK: Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveUrl = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")
```

Somebody could help me with this, please?

Comment: ArchiveUrl is a tuple, can you add code where ArchiveUrl is initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is right, and there should not be any error. Try to set type explicitly on ArchiveUrl like:

```
static let ArchiveUrl: URL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")
```

Comment: It works now. I have to make a Clean and Rebuild too. Thanks.